# Datadriven framework in Browserstack

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run my testcases in Browserstack emulation of different browsers. Test cases are developed in Hybrid framework. When I execute the test case, it ends displaying "Null pointer Exception". This happens when I execute the test case in Browserstack only and not the test run in eclipse. So wondering if BS supports Hybrid Framework. If yes,  please let me know what I need to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: This error is unlikely due to BrowserStack. When you say "test run in eclipse" - do you use webdriver or remotewebdriver ? Also, post the code and exception stack trace - without these its not possible to find the root cause.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. It runs in remotewebdriver.

Comment: @user4884895, did you find any solution to this. I am trying to execute my Hybrid Framework (Webdriver)in Browserstack. Not getting anywhere. Need help. Thanks